# Xcode Keyboard Lock

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard, locking

Hi can someone please help me..
I was playing around with a few shortcuts on xcode and somehow i mustve pressed at shortcut or something and now the keyboard is locked.. in the sense that i cant type, navigate or anything..
As far as i can tell, its only on xcode and i can use the keyboard everywhere else..

can anyone help?
:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up quiting the application.. and it does appear to have fixed itself..
Weird..

Comment: Seems like it was doing something and simply froze up, not that the keyboard locked itself.

Comment: I thought it probably was something along those lines.. I thought id killed xcode :O